# Почему не воспринимает стили?

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, чпу

```
RewriteRule ^stylesheet/([a-z-]+(.css))$ stylesheet.php?file=$1 [QSA]
```

Сделал ЧПУ на стили, теперь сайт их не воспринимают. Но они открываются. Как исправить?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet/home.css">
```

Вставляю так^

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['file'])) {
$file = 'pages/css/'.$_GET['file'];
if(file_exists($file)) {
include $file;
} else {
die('Ошибка: такого файла не существует!');
}
} else {
die('Ошибка: нет параметра file!');
}
?>
```

Код PHP^

[Пример CSS файла](http://istu.isize1ce.ru/stylesheet/home.css)

Comment: Надо как `Content-Type:text/css` отдавать, а сейчас у вас просто текстом идет. Посмотрите, например, как в [доках](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php) pdf отдают - здесь то же самое.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.